# How to fix the dependency error when installing a package? It comes in ubuntu 16

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am having the save problem and I tried with the above solutions but it does not work.
Is there any other way to fix it?
Can any one please help?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, and you mention Ubuntu 16 (no such release, Ubuntu Core 16 would be closest by name) but your picture seems to imply it's a *deb* based *yy.mm* release and not a *snap* based Ubuntu Core release. Please clarify with release details, and provide text so we can copy/paste and look up details.

Comment: It's quite obvious in the picture that there are versioning issues. The package needs newer dependency versions. You should consider installing a newer Ubuntu release.

Comment: try run sudo apt-get update --fix-missing and then upgrade softwares. Only after that it may be possible.

Comment: @guiverc
Hi
Thank you for the reply. 
The version is ubuntu 16.04.
And when I run the below code, I get these error message.

`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-fastcgi`

messages that I get is in below.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport : Depends: python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.23) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18 is to be installed
 debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python-samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.28) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.21 is to be installed

Thank you

Comment: @Stormlord I have run that fix code and then tried it again but it is yet not working. I can found the same message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first Update and Upgrade APT. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then clean unneccessary packages with `sudo apt-get autoclean`. Then run package diagnostics with `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Then run `sudo apt-get -f install` again and if you get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded` in the last line the APT is fixed. Install the package then.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it is not working. I have run all those command one by one and tried again but it is still showing the same issue.